# What is the mathematical framework for ordered sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, vectors

I can represent a collection of numbers as a set

$$
S = \left\lbrace  2, 5, 3, 1, 4 \right\rbrace
$$

and apply set-based operations:

$$
2 \in S, \quad 6 \notin S \; .
$$

Or I can represent a collection of numbers as a vector

$$
v = \left[ 2, 5, 3, 1, 4 \right]
$$

and access specific elements:

$$
v_1 = 2, \quad v_5 \neq 6 \; .
$$

But I can't do both, because sets are not ordered.

How can I do both? In brief, I want a mathematical structure to which all set-theoretic operations (membership, cardinality, power set, set difference etc.) as well as order-related operations ($i$-th element, set in reverse order etc.) can be applied. (It would also be nice, if the set-theoretic operations were defined to be order-preserving.)

Comment: Do you want only finite collections? What properties do you want on the order - for example, is it a total order or a well-order? The other thing vectors can have that sets can’t is repeated values. Of course, vectors don’t really have an order. Given any set $S$ we can define the vector space of all functions $S\to\mathbb R.$ We write vectors as ordered in introduction, but there might be no order in a vector space. (The vector space has an order if $S$ has an order.)

Comment: Finally, what purpose does this definition have? How we define things depends on what we want to do with them.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about totally-ordered sets.  You can do all the operations you like.  If you do the power set, you can apply the lexicographic order, ie, the order sets would appear in the dictionary; there are other choices of possible orders, though.

Comment: At heart, vectors and sets are unrelated concepts. They might have similar notations, but they have very different purposes

Comment: @JairTaylor Which is bigger, the set of even integers or the set of odd integers, in the lexicographer ordered ? You need a well-ordering to get a total order on the power set.

Comment: You can’t do things with ordered sets that you can with unordered sets. What is $[1,2]\cup[2,1]?$ $[1,2]\cap [2,1]?$

Comment: @JairTaylor Also, a total order doesn’t really allow “ordered sets.” At least as I’m reading it, we need the ordered set to allow ordered sets $[1,2]$ and $[2,1].$

Comment: Hmm, good points... union and intersection don't make sense, but the operations mentioned (membership, cardinality, power set, set difference) do.  Although you're right that lex-ordering the power set only makes sense if the original set was well-ordered.  As for $[1,2]$ and $[2,1]$, I don't see the problem... the first is $\{1,2\}$ with $1 < 2$ and the second is $\{1,2\}$ with $2 < 1$. They are distinct totally ordered sets albeit isomorphic. (I'm assuming you're not meaning $[1,2]$ as the interval.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your comments! Yes, $\left\lbrace 1,2 \right\rbrace$ and $\left\lbrace 2,1 \right\rbrace$ should be different objects when considered as ordered sets. I didn't notice so far, but you're right that some set-theoretic operations are in fact ambigous then. For my application, (i) the elements of the set should be distinct (i.e. no repetitions), (ii) union and intersection would not be required (but one could e.g. define primacy of the first set) and (iii) the power set does not need have a specific order (but it can).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The purpose of this is rewriting a product such as $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-b_i)$ into a sum. (In my case, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are square matrices, such that order is important.)